# How do I generate a JWT token in Android

Tags: android, jwt

I want to generate a JWT token in Android. I have the following questions:

1. What would be the Gradle dependencies?
2. Can anybody provide some sample Java code for the generation of a JWT token?

Comment: Use this:https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt/blob/master/README.md#jws-create

Answer (score 2):

You have to add Dependency like :

```
dependencies {
    api 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api:0.10.5'
    runtimeOnly 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl:0.10.5' 
    runtimeOnly('io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-orgjson:0.10.5') {
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }

}
```

and in proguard rules:

```
keepattributes InnerClasses

-keep class io.jsonwebtoken.** { *; }
-keepnames class io.jsonwebtoken.* { *; }
-keepnames interface io.jsonwebtoken.* { *; }

-keep class org.bouncycastle.** { *; }
-keepnames class org.bouncycastle.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.bouncycastle.**
```

you can find full docuenattion and sample from here :

https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt

Comment: can you please provide the java sample block of code to generate the JWT Token, which Will accept the custom secret key, hmac with some payload.